# Algebraic solution with radicals

Tags: equation-solving

```
GL = {P + u/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2] == 0, Q + v/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2] == 0, 
  R + w/Sqrt[u^2 + v^2] == 0}
Solve[GL, {u, v, w}]
```

The above has a Null return,how to solve it? Convert it to polynomials and adopt a Groebner basis? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

Problem arose when finding bisector of angle between straight lines

$ Ax+By+C =0\, $ and an outside line $u x+v y+ w=0,\,$ as

$$ \left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}-\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\right) x + \left(\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} - \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\right) y+ \left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}-\frac{w}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}\right)   =0 \,  $$

in  $D x+E y+F = 0 $ form so as to solve for $(u,v,w)$ coefficients of the outside line in terms of $ (A,B,C,D,E,F), or (P,Q,R) $ where

$$ P=D- \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}, \,Q= E-\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} , \,R= F-\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} $$

A Null result means that the mirror/outside line does no exist. Where is my oversight? ( Of course, more math than Mathematica) ..only I jumped at the prospect of  avoiding algebraic labour.

[MirrorLine_from_SEMath](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67024/the-equation-of-a-line-reflected-about-another-line)

[image: Finding (u,v,w) line]

Comment: In general your system is inconsistent. From the first and the second equations it is easy to see that it only has the solution, if `P^2+Q^2==1`. In that case the first and the second equations degenerate and `Solve` easily gives you `v -> (Sqrt[1 - P^2] u)/P`. Then you can address the third equation.

Comment: You did solve it. The solution set just happens to be empty.

Comment: "bisector of straight line" - surely you mean bisecting a line **segment**? Where would the "midpoint" be in an infinite line?

Comment: The updated question now seems more suited to [Math.SE]; would you like me to move your question to that site?

Comment: @J.M. It would be in the middle, of course. What I wonder about is what is meant by an "outside line". (Being outside, it is presumably exposed to the elements. Does it expand and contract? Is it brittle? Can we be certain it does not bend?)

Comment: Hope the above link clarifies it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, one line is intended to be the angle bisector of two others.If so, it would be good to restate the question, carefully, so that it is clear what is wanted.

Comment: added a figure showing the three lines

Comment: @J.M. To return to your question, let's take the worst-case scenario for our outside line, which is that it is outside in the desert. In the middle of the desert one finds camels. So we need to bisect a camel. Depending on whether our camel is bactrian or dromedary, this will result in a local min or max respectively. So now the question is reduced to two cases; is our desert in central Asia, or Africa/Asia Minor? I hope this settles the question.

Comment: @Daniel, but the Bactrian one is already pre-bisected. :)

Comment: Sorry, that ought to have read  "bisector of angle between between straight lines:" in first line of EDIT1